# Regex CSV-File Windows

Tags: regex, csv, salesforce, newline

Were planning to use a Data Export from Database to CSV to Salesforce.

We need some regex code to achieve in that way which is pointed out in the picture. I have experimented with some expressions which I've found but 
unfortunately I'm not good at it ...

So my csv file looks like this:

[image: CSV-With-Coments]

The comments point out what it should be accomplished by the regex.

Comment: Please, copy/paste the content of the image to the question by [editing it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33758932/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
perl -n -e 's/\"/{$i++;"\""}/eg; if (/^[\n\r]+$/ || $i % 2 != 0) {s/[\n\r]+$//} print' < input_file > output_file
```

The idea is simple. We count the number of quotes since the start of the input (`$i` variable). If this number is odd (that means the end of current string is inside a quoted clause), or if the string is empty (except for CR/LF characters), we remove trailing CR/LF characters from our string that caused it to be "glued" to the next string.

Comment: While this perl script may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.